# How is it possible to get (contact) Group ID's using a raw contact ID?

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
    //get group ID's
    // note: a contact can belong to multiple groups
    final String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactID
    + " AND "
    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

    final String[] projectionGroups = new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 };//DATA1 is GroupID

    Cursor curGroup = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            projectionGroups,
            where,
            null,
            null);

    if (curGroup != null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "group count "+curGroup.getCount());
    }
```

However, it always returns a count of 0.

Is there something wrong with the query ? I am using this on my phone running Android 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that's obviously wrong. However, I'm not convinced that contactID contains a value that can be found in the DATA table. In addition, are you certain that your contacts have groups enabled?

Comment: I believe the root of the problem is the way I obtain the "raw contact ID" in the first place. Currently I am using `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID`. I think this might be wrong.

Comment: What I need is a way to relate groups and contacts so that I can query what groups a contact belongs to.